Canned comments on "First Questions" review queue should be more useful and welcoming
I was going through the "first questions" review queue today, as I like welcoming people to a site I get a lot of value from. Now, it's been raised elsewhere that there is a lack of guidance for new users. They ask a question that is too broad, or don't share their research. One of the current canned comments reads:

"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer."

another:

"Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking."

That's super unhelpful - and unwelcoming - to a newbie user. What happens now is that I hand-write my messages, starting with a "welcome to SO" and pinpoint what is actually needed in this question, which can be either:

What have you tried, and where did it go wrong?
share your current research (links, code examples)
specify which programming language
why does the manual not answer your question? <- actual link to the manual/helpful text

Thus, a comment would then become:

"Welcome to SO! This question is too broad and doesn't provide detail. Could you share a minimal working example of what you tried and where it went wrong?"

Yes. I know you are bombarded with guidelines before posting a question. However, I think the general guidelines - to a newbie user - can be too broad: From these 20 things a question should be, which one applies to mine? That is where comments come in. But the default automated comments - that IMHO should provide an example for good comments - are really not how I would want to be greeting people on this website.
Can we expand the list of options for automated comments, and at the very least add a welcome message?

Exactly what I meant, didn't know the phrase. thanks for the edits! Since it's tagged feature-request, do downvotes mean that people don't like the feature?

Downvotes can mean users disagree with the feature request, or that they find the question poorly researched, and/or unclear, or simply not useful.

Most meta posts that start to unnecessarily throw the label "newbie" around like it is proof of something don't tend to fair very well. You're fixating and making assumptions. The only thing that can be said with certainty when a post enters the first questions queue is that it is someone's early attempts at asking questions. It says nothing about the person itself. And it doesn't matter anyway, because everyone deserves to be treated decently. Not welcoming... decently. That's enough for a site that is not social media.

"Could you share a minimal working example of what you tried and where it went wrong?" - While in 99% cases minimal working example could improve the question, in other 1% absence of such example is not a problem. Moreover, many "too broad" questions cannot be solved by adding an example - they need some other sort of "focusing-directed" fixes. Canned comments are emitted for all cases of a particular close vote/flag. I found it is better for a canned comment to be incomplete than to be misdirecting. If a reviewer wants to provide more specific guidance, they are free to write new comment

For one, a point could be made about the utility of canned comments. But then this misses the point a bit by proposing a mere rephrase comments to be somewhat more friendly.
The elephant in the room is that there is no way that a canned comment will be sufficiently focused to cover all feedback that the question could receive, and so the usefulness of that comment will always bear limitations.
At a certain point, you really need a custom comment to better serve the askers, albeit something which does require more time and effort from curators. Trying to sugarcoat the comments while saying the exact same information does not do anyone justice nor does it guarantee that the askers won't interpret it the wrong way.

As an addendum, the reason why this mechanism of canned comments exists is that askers want feedback, even before the question ultimately gets closed by the corresponding closure reason. And the reason why there is an option to make the community bot post them on the reviewer's behalf is because some askers realize they cannot handle that feedback with a level head.

indeed. Canned comments are quite standoffish in themselves. "You're not worth my time, here's just a standard cookie cutter reply and you figure it out from there". Might as well not do anything then and let someone with more time on their hands handle it.

@Gimby Eh, I’d still rather receive some sort of feedback than have nothing at all. While it’s a nice thought that “someone with more time on their hands” would handle it, I suspect you’d just end up with overall fewer instances of people receiving feedback.
